# iText - Fail on second attempt to generate PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a Java desktop application that is using iText to generate PDFs from a resultset.  The first time you generate a PDF, it works fine.  The problem comes when you try to generate a second one.  It throws a DocumentException saying that the document is closed.  I have tried to find other examples of people having this problem, and I come up with very little, which leads me to believe that I have made a very simple mistake and I cannot find it.

The code below is a snippet of the event handler that calls the report class:

```
RptPotReport report = new RptPotReport();
try {
    report.rptPot();
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is the code for the report class itself.  The error occurs on the second run through this code:

```
public class RptPotReport {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, SQLException {
        new RptPotReport().rptPot();
    }

    String fileOutput = "Potting Report.pdf";

    public void rptPot() throws DocumentException, IOException {
        File f = new File("Potting Report.pdf");
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }

        Document document = new Document();
        document = pdfSizes.getPdfLetter();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(fileOutput));
        document.open();

        Phrase title = new Phrase();
        title.add(new Chunk("Potting Report"));

        document.add(title); // ******* DocumentException here: "The document has been closed. You can't add any Elements."
        document.close();

        try {
            File pdfFile = new File(fileOutput);
            if (pdfFile.exists()) {
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported!");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: At someone's suggestion, I tried calling the RptPotReport from a second thread, but that did not change anything.  Looking into it further, the Document class of iText creates a new thread when it's instantiated.  So I'm right back where I started, still stuck.

Comment: Please edit your code: indent correctly, and reduce the size of it to a minimal example that reproduces the error. Also, mention which line throws the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does this line do exactly in your application:

`document = pdfSizes.getPdfLetter();`

Without the code and with your explanation it seems like the line sets the reference of the `document` variable to the one that you receive from `pdfSizes.getPdfLetter()`, which is reused between run, thus you no longer have the reference of the `new Document()` statement.

I tend to think the `pdfSizes.getPdfLetter()` method is bugged.